# Promoting object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object

So I have a class and another class that extends the first one.
I would like to know if it's possible to promote the extended class from the first one in JavaScript.

```
class Class1 {
  constructor(data) {
    this.var1 = data.var1
    this.var2 = data.var2
  }
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {
  constructor(o) {
    this = o
    this.var3 = '!!!'
  }
}

const o = new Class1({var1: 'HELLO', var2: 'WORLD'})
const o2 = new Class2(o)

console.log(o2.var1)
console.log(o2.var2)
```

I know that `this = o` is going to throw an error. But is there a way to accomplish the task without having to assign every field from the old object to a new one?

Comment: Should the `o` object be in the prototype chain of the `o2`, so that changes to `o` are observed from `o2`, or do you actually want the properties copied over? If copied, should they be deep copies if the values of those properties are objects?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `super()` function:

```js
class Class1 {
  constructor(data) {
    this.var1 = data.var1
    this.var2 = data.var2
  }
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {
  constructor(o) {
    super(o)
    this.var3 = '!!!'
  }
}

const o = new Class1({var1: 'HELLO', var2: 'WORLD'})
const o2 = new Class2(o)

console.log(o2.var1) // -> HELLO
console.log(o2.var2) // -> WORLD
```

More info on `super()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Should mention though that this does run the `Class1` constructor a second time, which may have undesired side-effects in some cases. Depends on the OP if this is a problem.

Comment: As an example of this approach leading to a bug: `Class1` may take a `data` object with fields `var1, var2, var3` and set `this.var3 = data.var3 + data.var1`. If that is the case, `var3` will have a different value for `o` and `o2` as the `Class1` constructor will override its value for `var3`. For this reason, you would be forced to design `Class1` in such a way that it specifically takes into account `Class1` objects in its constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can call `super(o)` at the beginning of the constructor on class2

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8kn7xcs/)

Comment: Well yes but what if ```class Class1 {
  constructor(data) {
    this.var10 = data.var1
    this.var11 = data.var2
  }
}``` ?

Comment: That changes the nature of the question, I don't think you can pass the object and having it automatically rename it's properties to match the constructor.

Comment: I am not really talking about automatic renaming. More like automatic promoting of Objects: 'https://jsfiddle.net/eaapd0e0/'